# fmt:formatNumber how to display deltas (+/-)

Tags: java, jsp, formatting, jstl

I want to use `fmt:formatNumber` to display the following:

1. `.8 => 80%`
2. `-.8 => -80%`
3. `1721 => 1,721`
4. `1721 => +1,721`
5. `-7876 => -7,876`

UPDATE: The format works perfectly for percent and grouping, but it doesn't work so well for putting a `+` in front of a number, as in the following:

1. `.8 => +80%`
2. `1721 => +1,721`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `%` pattern to "multiply by 100 and show as percentage". I think in your case you would need something like this:

```
// if num < 1 && num > -1 (or another logic)
<fmt:formatNumber value="${num}" format="%" />
// else
<fmt:formatNumber value="${num}" format="'+'###,###;'-'###,###" /> // show sign
```

*UPDATE*: You can use this method as well:

```
// if num < 1 && num > -1 (or another logic)
<fmt:formatNumber value="${num}" type="percentage" />
// else
<fmt:formatNumber value="${num}" type="number" groupingUsed="," />
```

Comment: Update for those who are reading this question now: the format property is now pattern, i.e. pattern="'+'###,###;'-'###,###"